# Changing Default Collation for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to change the default collation of SQL Server 2008 without having to reinstall the whole package ? It has to be Case Sensisitve by default - the application server I have checks this as a pre condition to installing and creating a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, but it is not for the faint of heart...

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx:

> Changing the default collation for an instance of SQL Server can be a
>   complex operation and involves the following steps:   Make sure you
>   have all the information or scripts needed to re-create your user
>   databases and all the objects in them.
>
> - Export all your data using a tool such as the [bcp Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). For more
>     information, see [Importing and Exporting Bulk Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).
> - Drop all the user databases.
> - Rebuild the master database specifying the new collation in the
>     SQLCOLLATION property of the setup command. For example:
>
> Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName 
>   /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts /[ SAPWD= StrongPassword ] 
>   /SQLCOLLATION=CollationName
>
> For more information, see [Rebuilding System Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).
>
> - Create all the databases and all the objects in them.
> - Import all your data.

If you can get away with just changing the default collation of the database(s) specific for the application, you may want to do that...